# Handling Built In iOS Permission Dialogs

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, dialog, ios-permissions

When loading my view controller for the first time, the user is prompted with a built in iOS permissions message: "Allow "appName" to access your location while you use the app?"

is there a way I can pause the app until the user either selects Don't Allow or Allow?

After the user selects Allow Or Dont Allow, I can handle it by checking the value like so:

```
//INSIDE OF ViewDidAppear

if(authstate != CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
{
 // do something
}
else if (authstate == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse)
{
  // do something
}
```

Right now the code steps through the if statement even though the iOS permissions dialog is still showing on the screen.  Therefore, I want to pause it until the user selects Allow or Dont Allow.  Then after the user selects either Allow or Dont Allow, continue onto the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. the permission request happens asynchronously. you have to implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`s method

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
  // check the status
}
```

that gets called after the user answered the permission dialogue.